# Why does the ideal $(f_1^N,\cdots,f_n^N)$ contain a power of the ideal $(f_1,\cdots,f_n)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'm reading the proof of Prop. I-18 in Eisenbud-Harris *The Geometry of Schemes* and I'm unsure of a claim they make. Let me just give you some necessary info:

Let $R$ be a commutative unital ring and let $f_1, \dots, f_n$ be elements of $R$ which generate the whole ring i.e. $(f_1, \dots, f_n) = R$. Let $g\in R$ and suppose there exist nonnegative integers $k_i (1\leq i \leq n)$ with $f_i^{k_i} g = 0$. Let $N$ be the maximum of these integers, so that $f_i^N g = 0$ for all $i$. The authors seem to make the claim that the ideal $(f_1^N, \dots, f_n^N)$ contains some power of the ideal $(f_1, \dots, f_n)=R$, but it is not clear to me why it should. Wouldn't any power of $(f_1, \dots, f_n)$ contain certain mixed products of the $f_i$ not divisible by any $f_i^N$?

Here is the (near) original statement which I have just altered slightly to replace $g=h$ to $g=0$ (you can find the original on page 19 [here](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/eisenbudharris.pdf)):

> This implies that $g$ is annihilated by a power of the ideal generated by all of the $f_a^N$ for some $N$. But this ideal contains a power of the ideal generated by all the $f_a$, which is the unit ideal. Hence $g=0$ in $R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The power $P=nN-n+1$ answers the question: indeed if all powers but one, say $k_i$, are $<N$, i.e. $k_j\le N-1$, then
$$k_i=P-\!\!\!\sum_{\substack{1\le j\le n\\j\ne i}}k_j\ge nN-n+1-(n-1)(N-1)=N.$$

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Bernard's answer, notice that elements of $(f_1,\dots,f_n)^r$ for some $r\geq 1$ are of the form (with $C(n,r)$ being the binomial coefficient): $$\sum_{i=1}^{C(n,r)} a_if_1^{r_{i1}}f_2^{r_{i2}}\dots f_n^{r_{in}}$$
for some elements $a_i\in R$ and integers $r_{ij}\geq 0$ such that
$\sum_{j=1}^n r_{ij}=r.$
All of this can easily be seen by induction on $r$. We can see that as $r$ increases while $n$ stays constant, there's some kind of pigeonhole principle at work here that will eventually cause at least one of the $r_{ij}$ for each summand $i$ to be greater or equal to $N$.

We can work out explicitly a value of $r$ at which this phenomenon is guaranteed to occur. The result is exactly Bernard's answer.